# How to get HTML page CSS to apply to PDF files

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML to PDF file I am trying to create.
One side of the HTML document has a background color that runs through the page.
I want this left-side background to apply to all converted PDF files.
Please refer to this image to see:
[image]

The left-sided background should go right through each PDF document page.
Here is the CSS of the file:

```
 body, html {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    html {
        position: relative;
        min-height: 100%;
    }
    
    .container {
        width: 100%;
        background: indigo;
    }
    p {
        
    }
    .clearfix {
        clear: both !important;
    }
    .row {
       width: 100%;
       position: relative;
       height: 100%;
       background: indigo;
    }
    .col-left {
        background: indigo;
        min-height: 578mm;
        height: 100%;
        width: 30%;
        color: white;
        float: left;
    }
    .col-right {
        background-color: white;
        width: 70%;
        float: left; 
    }
```

Can this be fixed through just CSS?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the left column to occupy the whole screen height, maybe something like this:

```css
body {
margin: 0px;
}

.left {
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
background-color: purple;
width: 150px;
}

.content {
padding-left: 160px;
height: 1553px;
}

.content-inside {
background-color: yellow;
height: 100%;
}

h1 {
margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="content"> 
<div class="content-inside">
  <h1>content goes here</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That didn't work. Same results are without the fixed property

Comment: Can you also post the HTML code? Im curious rn

Comment: I used the same Html u used above!!

Comment: That's.. weird. `position: fixed` plus `height: 100%` should occupy all the screen height, since it ignores what's behind, because of the position. What actually happens, in your code?

Comment: Oh yeah. Works for the first page of pdf file, but not the second page of pdf document

Comment: @KJ I am using python pdfkit to generate the pdf.  It may be a problem with pdfkit??